# Separate stage manager controls per display?

Tags: stage-manager

I am using a dual monitor setup. I wonder if there's a way to turn on stage manager for one display and turn it off for the other? I believe there's no official way to do it, but I am very much open to installing a plugin or other non-conventional solutions.

Comment: It's only been out 5 minutes! I doubt anyone's written something to mess with it. It's certainly worth sending in a feature request to Apple feedback.